# Different chapter headings for odd and even pages

Tags: sectioning, double-sided, fncychap

Is there a way to have different chapter headings for odd and even starting chapters using `fncychap` with `scrbook` class? I'm using a personal style (a mix of Sonny and Bjornstrup) that has a large chapter number on the right that is not clearly visible when chapter starts on even pages.

Edit:

This is style definition in `fncychap.sty`

```
%%%%%%PERSONAL DEF

\DeclareOption{Personal}{%
  \ChNameVar{\Large\sf}
  \ChNumVar{ \fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m} {n}\selectfont\color{darkgray}}}
  \ChTitleVar{\Large\sf\em\color{Sepia}}
  \ChRuleWidth{0.5pt}
  \ChNameUpperCase
  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
   \vskip -100\p@%
    \raggedleft
     \Huge\CNoV\thechapter

}
  \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedleft\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@}
  \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedleft\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@}
```

And this is a pic of the output (sorry for low quality, only way to post it from netbook)[image: Output]

This chapter starts on odd page. I'm searching for a way to move the large chapter number on left when chapter starts on even page.

Comment: Please add a minimal example showing your "personal style" and describe how exactly it should be modified for even pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using a conditional test:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%PERSONAL DEF

\DeclareOption{Personal}{%
  \ChNameVar{\Large\sf}
  \ChNumVar{ \fontsize{76}{80}\usefont{OT1}{pzc}{m} {n}\selectfont\color{darkgray}}}
  \ChTitleVar{\Large\sf\em\color{Sepia}}
  \ChRuleWidth{0.5pt}
  \ChNameUpperCase
  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
   \vskip -100\p@%
    \ifodd\c@page
    \raggedleft
    \else
    \raggedright
    \fi
     \Huge\CNoV\thechapter

}
  \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedleft\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@}
  \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedleft\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was searching for, I didn't know how to format if cicle.