# Fancy Chapter Headings Right for Odd Pages and Left of Left ones

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters

I have those two parts of code:

```
\documentclass[double,12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

%--------------first one-----------------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
{10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

%--------------second one-----------------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedright}
{\hspace{0cm}\llap{%
        \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}\hspace{0.2cm}\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.2cm}}%
    \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}}
{10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I want the first one for the odd pages and the second one for the even ones.
I am new with latex, and I couldn't figure out from [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70038/different-chapter-headings-for-odd-and-even-pages) thread.

PS. I am sorry for duplicate question, how can i delete one question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To delete a question simply click on the **delete** button on the bottom left corner of the question box. The question you've linked to uses a KOMA-Script class, things differ a bit from KOMA and standard classes.

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: Yes I do, posted as an answer! `;)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same logic proposed in the question, checking wheter to see if the page is odd or not. KOMA and `memoir` have built in functions for that, but the `book` class doesn't. There was already one question about this in the Website: [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page). The package `changepage` was one of the recomentadions. Then to change the `\chapter` format, use the `titlesec` package.

But for this to take effect you have to load the `book` class with the `openany` option, as by default it's set to `openright`, then the chapters headings would never end up on an even page. Also, you don't need the `geometry` package for setting the paper to A4, you can pass that directly to the class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, double, 12pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\normalfont\Large\checkoddpage%
\ifoddpage%
  \raggedleft%
\else%
  \raggedright%
\fi}%
{\checkoddpage%
\ifoddpage%
 \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
 \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}%
\else%
  \hspace{0cm}\llap{%
    \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}\hspace{0.2cm}\resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter}\hspace{0.2cm}}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
\fi}
{10pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Odd page}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Even page}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thnx a lot !!!!